# Pod restart very often after adding resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

Pod restart very often after adding resources.

Before that the resources were not added.
The pod doesn't restart at all, or maybe it only happens once or twice a day.

I'm not sure if resources affect health-check or not, so pod restarts very often.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testservice-dpm
  labels:
    app: testservice-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testservice-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testservice-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testservice
        image: testservice:v6.0.0
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PORT
          value: "1433"
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1000Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: test-p
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test-v
          mountPath: /app/appsettings.json
          subPath: appsettings.json
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 1
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 1
      volumes:
      - name: test-v
        configMap:
            name: testservice-config
```

Below are the results describe all of the testservice pods.

1. testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-rwxr4
   (restart 7 times in 10 minutes and still Back-off restarting failed container now)

```
Name:         testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-rwxr4
Namespace:    testapi
Priority:     0
Node:         workernode3/yyy.yyy.yy.yy
Start Time:   Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:48:50 +0700
Labels:       app=testservice-api
              pod-template-hash=d7979cc69
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-12-29T20:02:45Z
Status:       Running
IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
IPs:
  IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69
Containers:
  testservice:
    Container ID:   docker://86a50f98b48bcf8bfa209a478c1127e998e36c1c7bcece71599f50feabb89834
    Image:          testservice:v6.0.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://testservice@sha256:57a3955d07febf4636eeda1bc6a18468aacf66e883d7f6d8d3fdcb5163724a84
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:55:13 +0700
      Finished:     Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:55:19 +0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1000Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   100Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Readiness:  http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:
      MSSQL_PORT:  1433
    Mounts:
      /app/appsettings.json from authen-v (rw,path="appsettings.json")
      /etc/localtime from tz-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-fd9bt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  authen-v:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      testservice-config
    Optional:  false
  tz-config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok
    HostPathType:  File
  kube-api-access-fd9bt:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  11m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned testapi/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-rwxr4 to workernode3
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m (x2 over 11m)   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness": dial tcp xx.xxx.x.xxx:80: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m (x3 over 11m)   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m (x3 over 11m)   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Normal   Killing    11m (x3 over 11m)   kubelet            Container testservice failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Created    10m (x4 over 11m)   kubelet            Created container testservice
  Normal   Started    10m (x4 over 11m)   kubelet            Started container testservice
  Normal   Pulled     10m (x4 over 11m)   kubelet            Container image "testservice:v6.0.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    80s (x51 over 11m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

2. testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-7nq28
   (restart 4 times in 10 minutes and running now)

```
Name:         testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-7nq28
Namespace:    testapi
Priority:     0
Node:         workernode3/yyy.yyy.yy.yy
Start Time:   Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:47:37 +0700
Labels:       app=testservice-api
              pod-template-hash=d7979cc69
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-12-29T20:02:45Z
Status:       Running
IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
IPs:
  IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69
Containers:
  testservice:
    Container ID:   docker://03739fc1694370abda202ba56928b46fb5f3ef7545f527c2dd73764e55f725cd
    Image:          testservice:v6.0.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://testservice@sha256:57a3955d07febf4636eeda1bc6a18468aacf66e883d7f6d8d3fdcb5163724a84
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:48:44 +0700
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:48:10 +0700
      Finished:     Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:48:14 +0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  4
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1000Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   100Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Readiness:  http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:
      MSSQL_PORT:  1433
    Mounts:
      /app/appsettings.json from authen-v (rw,path="appsettings.json")
      /etc/localtime from tz-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-slz4b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  authen-v:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      testservice-config
    Optional:  false
  tz-config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok
    HostPathType:  File
  kube-api-access-slz4b:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned testapi/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-7nq28 to workernode3
  Warning  Unhealthy  14m (x2 over 14m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness": dial tcp xx.xxx.x.xxx:80: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  14m (x3 over 14m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  14m (x3 over 14m)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Normal   Killing    14m (x3 over 14m)  kubelet            Container testservice failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  BackOff    14m (x2 over 14m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Started    14m (x4 over 14m)  kubelet            Started container testservice
  Normal   Pulled     14m (x4 over 14m)  kubelet            Container image "testservice:v6.0.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    14m (x4 over 14m)  kubelet            Created container testservice
```

3. testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-z566c
   (no restart in 10 minutes and running now)

```
Name:         testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-z566c
Namespace:    testapi
Priority:     0
Node:         workernode3/yyy.yyy.yy.yy
Start Time:   Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:47:30 +0700
Labels:       app=testservice-api
              pod-template-hash=d7979cc69
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-12-29T20:02:45Z
Status:       Running
IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
IPs:
  IP:           xx.xxx.x.xxx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69
Containers:
  testservice:
    Container ID:   docker://19c3a672cd8453e1c5526454ffb0fbdec67fa5b17d6d8166fae38930319ed247
    Image:          testservice:v6.0.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://testservice@sha256:57a3955d07febf4636eeda1bc6a18468aacf66e883d7f6d8d3fdcb5163724a84
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:47:31 +0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1000Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   100Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckLiveness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Readiness:  http-get http://:80/api/ServiceHealth/CheckReadiness delay=3s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:
      MSSQL_PORT:  1433
    Mounts:
      /app/appsettings.json from authen-v (rw,path="appsettings.json")
      /etc/localtime from tz-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cpdnc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  authen-v:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      testservice-config
    Optional:  false
  tz-config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok
    HostPathType:  File
  kube-api-access-cpdnc:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  16m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned testapi/testservice-dpm-d7979cc69-z566c to workernode3
  Normal  Pulled     16m   kubelet            Container image "testservice:v6.0.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    16m   kubelet            Created container testservice
  Normal  Started    16m   kubelet            Started container testservice
```

Comment: Without more information, it's hard for us to have any idea. Try the logs of the container (`kubectl logs -f containerName`) or `kubectl describe pod containerName`

Comment: @Cjmarkham I've added more information from describe pods.

Comment: Well, it says the connection was refused when trying to ping the liveness endpoint. Try increasing the `initialDelaySeconds` to something like `10` and see if that helps. Could just be a race condition.